# If two measures are equal, are the integrals with respect to these measures equal?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures such that $\mu=\nu$, then   is it true that for all measurable function $f$ $$\int fd\mu=\int fd\nu \ \ \ ?$$

It is true for integrable functions but if $ f $ is measurable  I'm not sure.

If someone could give some light on this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: "Equals can be substituted for equals" is a rather fundamental principle of logic.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I'd go further and say that two things are equal if and only if one has, *for all purposes and intents* exactly the same properties as the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two measures are equal (meaning they are defined on the same $\sigma$-algebra and attain equal values on every element of $\sigma$-algebra), then they are the same measure for all considerations.

Thus, as long as we can make sense out of $\int f\,d\mu$ and $\int f\,d\nu$, these integrals are equal. And we can make sense out of them if either the positive or the negative part of $f$ is integrable. Otherwise they are undefined, and then the equality makes no sense. I guess you could still say that $$\text{undefined}=\text{undefined}$$
 but why?

Comment: +1. As you well know, the three situations you indicate as examples are actually the only cases when the integrals make sense. This fact might be added to the answer.